# I need to create a table on webpage from shell script output file in php

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6rcy.jpg)

This is my code :
$myfile = file_get_contents('/ftpfiles/monitor-data') or die ("Unable");
    //$new_array = array_chunk($myfile, 9);
    //$new_array = array_filter(explode("\n", file_get_contents('/ftpfiles/monitor-data') or die ("Unable")));
    //$length = count($new_array);
        //print_r($new_array)
    $table = '';
    $filearray = explode(" ", $myfile);
    //var_dump($filearray);

```
foreach($filearray as $value)
{
$table .= '<tr><td align = "center">'.$value.'</td></tr>';

}
$table.='</table>';

echo $table;
```

But I am getting just one row, how can I create 9 columns for one row. I tried using Value[0].. value[8] but just broke whole string into single characters.

Comment: Your problem is that you are displaying 9 rows instead of 1 row and 9 columns ?

Comment: yea. I want to display 13 rows and 9 columns but everything is going in one columns

Comment: Could you please take a moment to make this question at least slightly presentable?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to explode your rows as well (as you are doing it with the entire file) :

```
$myfile = file_get_contents('/ftpfiles/monitor-data') or die("Unable");
$table = '<table border="3">';
$filearray = explode(" ", $myfile);

foreach($filearray as $row) {
    // here separate your row that is a string, into an array
    $cols = explode(" ", $row);
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach($cols as $value) {
        $table .= '<td align = "center">'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table.='</table>';

echo $table;
```

Of course, that implies that all your rows will explode in the same amount of columns. If you monitor-data file differs from one line to another, you should adapt the code to parse each row.

Comment: Same result, everything goes in one row!

Comment: Thank You ! I removed row end </tr> from the mentioned line and it worked  $table .= '<td align = "center">'.$value.'</td></tr>';

Comment: I know its silly question, how can  I  put header as first row in a table?

Comment: it depends if you know for sure how many columns you're gonna have in your table. If you do now, you can add some html to your $table var before entering the first foreach ($table .= '<tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2.....</tr>). If you don't know, the cleanest way would be to reconstruct a php array with your rows and columns, to ensure you have the same number of columns in each rows and then you could add a row on the top of your array with your headers. Then you would just have to browse your array to output your html table.

Comment: I do know number of columns, but if I put header on top, it does not align with array output. I am trying this " $table .= '<thead class = "cen"><tr><th>Colname1</th><th>Colname2</th><th align = "center">Colname3</th><th align = "center">Colname4</th><th align = "center">Colname5</th><th align = "center">Colname6</th><th align = "center">Colname7</th><th align = "center">Colname8</th><th align = "center">Colname9</th></tr></thead>'; "